# TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, recaptcha

I am using google recaptcha before a form submit in my angular js application and it is working fine for the first time but if i try to submit the form second time(same form) it is showing the error 
`angular.js:14525 TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null`

My recaptcha code is

```
<div vc-recaptcha key="my key here" ng-model="letter.myRecaptchaResponse" on-create="setRecaptchaId(widgetId)"> </div>
```

My controller code is

```
$scope.setRecaptchaId = function(widgetId) {
    $scope.recaptchaId = widgetId;
    return;
};
$scope.letter.mresponse = vcRecaptchaService.getResponse($scope.recaptchaId);
```

Actually if i refresh the form after first submit everything is working fine, feeling strange about it. I took suggestions from this [click here](https://github.com/VividCortex/angular-recaptcha/issues/81) but nothing solved my issue.

Comment: Where is letter.myRecaptchaResponse defined?

Comment: @AnthonyMcGrath it is not defined i am getting the value from that after checking recaptcha google is giving that value.

Comment: Is widgetId defined?

Comment: no, not defined if i am not wrong it automatically come form google recaptcha.

Answer (score 0):

First set:

```
$scope.letter.myRecaptchaResponse = '';
```

within `ng-init`.